# NOT all records getting loaded into TGT Snowflake DB from Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing a UNLOAD from redshift & COPY into Snowflake DB. Tried to unload & copy based on date.
When the record count was 30k, only ~25k records got loaded adn no errors was shown.
After removing the SKIP BLANK in COPY command of Snowflake, all records got loaded into target snowflake db. While verifying the missing records, couldn't find anything strange.

Has anyone come across like this or any inputs on these types of issues?

Comment: Can you show your copy command? There is no `skip blank` option for the `COPY` in Snowflake.

Comment: The actual command is SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE

Comment: It sounds like the file you unloaded from Redshift has ~5k of blank lines in it or NULLs. Have you checked if the file you unloaded from Redshift has lines which contain no data?

Comment: Yes.. I did.. there were no blank lines or any new line character that breaks a line..
Also the row that i checked has data in it and no NULL.

Comment: Same experience!  SKIP_BLANK_LINES=true caused fewer records to load from files with no blank lines.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: I just wanted to let everyone know Snowflake has identified the bug (at least from a similar use case that was reported) and this will be fixed in a future release (can monitor release notes). Please file a Snowflake Support case if you do not see it resolved with the fix.